# The best method to build a multi-language Drupal 6 site?

Tags: drupal, web, multilingual

I found many articles on the web but most of them are so old and written for drupal 5 or even 4. I'm looking for recent modules or recent updated modules for drupal 6. And a manual on how to use them.
I already found this article http://drupal.org/node/275705 which is pretty good but also more then 2 years old so probably not up to date.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use:

1. i18n-6.x-1.5.tar.gz
2. l10n_client-6.x-1.8.tar.gz
3. lang_dropdown-6.x-1.2.tar.gz
4. languageinterface-6.x-2.5.tar.gz
5. multicurrency-6.x-1.x-dev.tar.gz

Note that you best try all these modules first, and when you start building your site, start from scratch and do some planning. There may be issues otherwise with pages that cannot be found / accessed and so on.

Especially with the following modules I had some issues:

1. front-6.x-1.2.tar.gz
2. tcontact-6.x-1.1.tar.gz

The language interface comes in very handy and allows you to look for strings on a page and immediately translate them. If you are really going multilingual, you may consider using the transliteration module as well when you are storing files etc.

Greetz,
Joachim

Comment: thanks I'll try this, are you sure this is up to date info, because a lot of drupal info is so damn old?

Comment: Yes, I did this on a site one month ago. Currently, I am reviewing the localization process for drupal, and I am writing a white paper about it. I will let you know more as soon as it is finished.